# Resize feature with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, qgis-processing

This code adds a `QgsPoint` to a layer. **But how to increase the size of feature ?**

```
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'points' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pt = QgsFeature()
point1 = QgsPoint(-4080198.52,1492348.027)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

Answer (score 1):

A point is a thing of zero dimensions, and cannot be increased in size. Is it possible you mean 'increase size of point symbol with PyQGIS'? In this case I suggest reading about single symbol renderers in the PyQGIS developer cookbook: http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/de/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#single-symbol-renderer

Comment: i think a buffer can work well but .. i don't know how to create buffer around that point .. i am new to qgis.. any help?

Comment: Since `QgsPoint()` has no `buffer()` method you have to first convert it to a `QgsGeometry()` and buffer this by means of `g = QgsGeometry().fromPoint(QgsPoint(1,1)).buffer(10,100)`. You allready did this step in your code. For `buffer()` refer to https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ab7302c054a2c5514222b4bd71df71ab8

Comment: i didn't get **buffer(10,100)**

Comment: right, but all the steps before ;-)